# How to write two test cases for toggling boolean value in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

Need to write unit test case(s) for a function that toggles one boolean

This is for Angular 6 and Jasmine.  The function is elementary and works as expected.  However, I'm novice with Jasmine (and unit test cases) and my test cases are failing.

```
// This works as expected
toggle() {
   this.expand = !this.expand;
}
```

```
// These test cases fail
it('should toggle', () => {
  this.expand = false;
  component.toggle();
  expect(this.expand).toBe(true);
});

it('should toggle', () => {
  this.expand = true;
  component.toggle();
  expect(this.expand).toBe(false);
});
```

Expected boolean value should be the opposite of what it currently is prior to running the function.

Comment: Is this toggle function inside a component or inside a service or a global function?

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig Great question.  This toggle function is inside of an Angular component and when the component is initialized, I have set the boolean as false:

  expand: Boolean = false;

Comment: Well inside your test you won't be able to access the expand property with ```this``` then but rather use the fixture.componentInstance to access everything from your component. Usually inside a generated test from the cli the fixture.componentInstance is already assigned to a constant ```component```

Answer (score 4):

I think you might need to use component instance

```
// These test cases fail
it('should toggle', () => {
  component.expand = false;
  component.toggle();
  expect(component.expand).toBe(true);
});

it('should toggle', () => {
  component.expand = true;
  component.toggle();
  expect(component.expand).toBe(false);
});
```